# How to access a postgres container through its name? Could not translate host name error

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have a django and postgres containers. When it's time for django to apply migrations, it doesn't see a postgres container that I named pgdb and I get this error:

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "pgdb"
> to address: Temporary failure in name resolution

It appears that there is no docker container with name "pgdb". If I run "docker-compose run pgdb" it creates a postgres container with a name of "app_pgdb_run_23423423" under the "app" group. The cute thing is that I made it work previously with this settings.py setup and "pgdb" postgres container name. What could be the underlying issue?

You can clone the full code from https://github.com/UberStreuner/mailing-service

My settings.py setup, the environment variables definitely aren't at fault.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': os.environ.get('DB_ENGINE', 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2'),
        'NAME': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_DB'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_HOST', 'pgdb'),
        'PORT': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_PORT', '5432')
    }
}
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  django:
    build: .
    container_name: django
    command: ./docker-entrypoint.sh
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app/
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    env_file:
      - ./.dev.env
    depends_on:
      - pgdb
      - redis

  celery:
    build: .
    command: celery -A mailing worker -l INFO
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app/
    env_file:
      - ./.dev.env
    depends_on:
      - django
      - redis
      - pgdb

  celery-beat:
    build: .
    command: celery -A mailing beat -l INFO
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app/
    env_file:
      - ./.dev.env
    depends_on:
      - django
      - redis
      - pgdb

  pgdb:
    image: postgres
    container_name: pgdb
    env_file:
      - ./.dev.env
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    expose:
      - "5432"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"

volumes:
  pgdata:
```

.dev.env

```
SECRET_KEY=django-insecure-kh8ot+ag-^osyhg5itzj!iw_g#dklw3f75c0)^-7)*@^)#tc#x
DEBUG=1

DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS=localhost 127.0.0.1
CELERY_BROKER=redis://redis:6379/0
CELERY_BACKEND=redis://redis:6379/0

POSTGRES_DB=django_postgres
POSTGRES_USER=postgres
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
```

docker-entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Comment: Do both containers are in the same network?
you can check this by pinging the pgdb from your container terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue.
It probably was in the fact that I import the environment variables for Django from both python-dotenv through .dev.env file and from docker-compose, where it's passed as env_file. So I commented out dotenv loading from settings.py, and it worked.